# Magento2 : How to Fix module version

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade

I have installed a module. it gives me below error.

[image]

I Have tried to increase the version to 2.0.3  then error is not showing up but the module is not working.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Even after doing all this, this module is not working as expected.

**How I can I remove the module completely from Magento and make a fresh Installation of the module.**

I have tried removing the module and `setup:upgrade` & pasting again Code 
 and `setup:upgrade`.

Cause this module is upgrading schema also. when I install it is not updating the Tables with new Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completely remove the extension from your magento, you need to follow these steps.

- First, disable the module. php bin/magento module:disable K2B_PickPay
- Now upgrade of your database by setup upgrade command
- Go to the database and find the table **setup_module** and search for
  your module entry "K2B_PickPay" and delete that.
- Delete the database table that is related to this module.
- Remove the code from app/code directory
- Then remove all cache folders from var/ directory
- Now execute these commands one by one.

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:flush**

That's it. Your module is completely removed from Magento and you can make fresh installation again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **K2B_Pickpay** module from **setup_module** table.

Run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the module completely:

- First, run the following command to disable the module:

> php bin/magento module:disable K2B_PickPay

- Remove module's entry from the setup_module table.
- Remove all tables which were created by the module (if any).
- Remove custom columns added by the module (if any).
- To confirm that module has been uninstalled, run the following
  command from project's directory:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

- Flush Magento cache.
- Copy module files again in the project's folder and re-run the following command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

and

> php bin/magento module:enable K2B_PickPay

If your module has to deploy static content, then run the following command:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 0):

You have imported a database with the older version. Due to that, this version issue came. 
I suggest go to your DB >> setup_module table >> find those two modules in that table >> update version as 2.0.3. And run setup:upgrade command.

Hope this will help you.